# Use of gerund with ablative of means or method

Tags: grammar-identification, ablative, gerund

A beginner's question: when using an ablative of means/method where the means/method in question is a verb, does that verb take the gerund ablative form? This is the sentence which prompted the question:

"..ac prope Tiberim fluvium, quem prae se armentum agens *nando* transierat,.."

Which I translate as:

"..and by the river Tiber, which driving the herd before him *he had crossed by swimming*,..".

Have I understood this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly right.

Nando or natando means "by swimming".